# Create a new key and assign the value of an existing key in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

This is how the nested dictionary looks like :

```
mydict = {
    'a1':{
        'x': 1,
        'y': 2
    },
    'a2':{
        'x':3,
        'y':4
    }
}
```

I am trying to add a new key `z` in dictionaries `a1` and `a2` such that the new key contains the value of key `x`.

Currently, I am using this approach :

```
for key in mydict:
  mydict[key]['z'] = mydict[key]['x']
```

Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: What is the problem with how you are currently doing it?

Comment: @GiladGreen I am not facing any problem as such but out of curiosity looking for other methods which might be more efficient than the current one like using dict's built in methods to do so, also I might be dealing with larger number of such dictionaries in the future, so using my approach might be time consuming

Comment: Do you want this behavior to happen only with the key `'z'` or any new key in the dictionnary?

Comment: @LucG Yes only key `z`

Comment: Even if you use dict's bulitin method to achieve that,I think it will be hard to read.(And efficiency will not improve).`O(n)` time complexity is enough because you want to update each key-value pair in the dict.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA What about @LucG 's proposal? Using a custom dict class does indeed reduce the complexity to `O(1)` for this specific use-case.

Comment: His solution is what to do when you create the dict.But if you want to update the dict when you **have created** it,it should be `O(n)`.On the other hand,if so,there are better way to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your loop approach. You can be a little more concise iterating over the inner dicts directly:

```
for d in mydict.values():
    d['z'] = d['x']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own `zdict` class! If you are sure that the dict will get a `x` key at init you can set `z` at `__init__`. Otherwise, you can design you own `__getitem__` method to behave as you would like. I provide the two solutions.

```
class zdict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self['z'] = self['x']

class zdict2(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item == 'z':
            return super().__getitem__('x') # note that you can't modify the value of "z" anymore in that implementation but you can figure something to change that
        else:
            return super().__getitem__(item)


mydict = {
    'a1': zdict(
        x=1,
        y=2
    ),
    'a2':zdict(
        x=3,
        y=4
    ),
}

print(mydict['a1']['z'], mydict['a1']['x'])
print(mydict['a2']['z'], mydict['a2']['x'])



mydict2 = {
    'a1': zdict2(
        x=1,
        y=2
    ),
    'a2':zdict2(
        x=3,
        y=4
    ),
}

print(mydict2['a1']['z'], mydict2['a1']['x'])
print(mydict2['a2']['z'], mydict2['a2']['x'])
```

Comment: That is a lot of boilerplate compared to two lines though.

Comment: 4 lines actually in the first case and `O(1)` complexity overall ;) . But I agree, it is more.... circumvunted...

Comment: For example,if now exist `mydict = {'a1':{'x': 1,'y': 2 },'a2':{'x':3,'y':4}}`.How did you convert it to that?`for key in mydict:xxxxx`?

Comment: In that case there is no other option than looping over keys in mydict. But I can do `mydict = {key: zdict(**value) for key, value in mydict}` if I want to use my `zdict`, which is merely the same as op's solution. OP was obviously looking for out-of-the-box thinking on the problem. I provided him with that. I don't say this is the best solution ever in all situations. But It can be a better solution than his in some situations, `zdict2` in particular.

Comment: You can initialize `zdict2` with a mapping of key aliases, like `aliases = {'z': 'x'}`. Then `__getitem__` can call `super().__getitem__(aliases.get(item, item))`. The extra lookup is O(1).

Comment: @LucG. I'm pretty sure that `zdict(value.items())` is going to be more efficient than `zdict(**value)`

Comment: Yep! I like it! It removes the if block!

Comment: @MadPhysicist I've just tried it with `%timeit`, this is roughly the same: `1.53 µs ± 104 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)` with `**value` and `1.6 µs ± 16.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)` with `value.items()`

Comment: So `mydict = {key: zdict(**value) for key, value in mydict}` is `O(n)` ,That's what I mean.If OP really just want to do some operations when create it,there will have better idea.Whatever,your idea is also a solution.

Comment: In my case, `x` and `z` are default and current values of some parameter, so `x` remains constant throughout and `z` is equal to `x` during init until changed to some other value after  init by some other function. Also I am trying to add `z` to existing dictionary, so modification using zdict is ruled out, thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT1:** Not arguing about efficiency here because I have not benchmarked both solutions!

---

**EDIT2:** If you want to keep the key `'x'` use:

```
mydict = { k: {'z': v['x'], **v} for k, v in mydict.items() }
```

---

No as readable as your solution though I think of it to be more pythonic is this:

```
mydict = { k: {'z': v.pop('x'), **v} for k, v in mydict.items() }
```

Comment: Here is a repl.it to test it yourself: https://repl.it/repls/PleasingLimitedUnderstanding

Comment: Thanks for your comment @jizhihaoSAMA. I updated my answer to make it clear that I do not make *any* claims on efficiency here.

Comment: This removes key `x`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SaurabhPBhandari. Please see my EDIT2.

Comment: Your solution is 2.5 times slower than the original one. Not sure why you think it is better.

Comment: @DYZ Thanks, that is correct. I did a quick and simple repl.it to corroborate your argument: https://repl.it/repls/FortunateJuicyPhp .

As stated earlier, I do not have any claims about efficiency but a mere alternative solution. I think the code the OP posted is already pretty neat and I would have done it the same when coding. I simply wanted to provide an alterantive solution.

Comment: This creates a new dictionary for each outer value.